# I have this query that gives me the following php array data:

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Here is the foreach loop to get data in an array.

```
 foreach ($data['songsPlayList'] as $key => $value){
                    $data['playlistSongs'] = $this->_song->getSongsInPlaylist($value);
                    //var_dump($data['playlistSongs']);

                }
```

If I view the source , I will see this :

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "121"
    [0]=>
    string(3) "121"
    ["artist"]=>
    string(12) "2face Idibia"
    [1]=>
    string(12) "2face Idibia"
    ["song_title"]=>
    string(13) "African Queen"
    [2]=>
    string(13) "African Queen"
    ["filename"]=>
    string(30) "2face Idibia-African Queen.mp3"
    [3]=>
    string(30) "2face Idibia-African Queen.mp3"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "493"
    [0]=>
    string(3) "493"
    ["artist"]=>
    string(10) "Lucky Dube"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "Lucky Dube"
    ["song_title"]=>
    string(11) "Remember Me"
    [2]=>
    string(11) "Remember Me"
    ["filename"]=>
    string(26) "Lucky Dube-Remember Me.mp3"
    [3]=>
    string(26) "Lucky Dube-Remember Me.mp3"
  }
}
```

With this, I can only print out the results one array. So what I want to do is convert it to an array like this :

```
array(437) {
  [0]=>
  array(12) {
     ["id"]=>
    string(3) "121"
    [0]=>
    string(3) "121"
    ["artist"]=>
    string(12) "2face Idibia"
    [1]=>
    string(12) "2face Idibia"
    ["song_title"]=>
    string(13) "African Queen"
    [2]=>
    string(13) "African Queen"
    ["filename"]=>
    string(30) "2face Idibia-African Queen.mp3"
    [3]=>
    string(30) "2face Idibia-African Queen.mp3"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(12) {
      ["id"]=>
    string(3) "493"
    [0]=>
    string(3) "493"
    ["artist"]=>
    string(10) "Lucky Dube"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "Lucky Dube"
    ["song_title"]=>
    string(11) "Remember Me"
    [2]=>
    string(11) "Remember Me"
    ["filename"]=>
    string(26) "Lucky Dube-Remember Me.mp3"
    [3]=>
    string(26) "Lucky Dube-Remember Me.mp3"
  }
}
```

So I can do a php foreach loop to get all the result data. Any suggestions?

Comment: `var_dump($data);` instead of `var_dump($data['playlistSongs']);` and place it under the loop, not inside of it. aaand: replace `$data['playlistSongs']` with `$data['playlistSongs'][]`.

Comment: This gives me just one result, but I have more than one data  array result when in the foreach loop

Comment: anonther solution: use array_map. this could look like something like this: `$data = array_map(function($song) use($this) { return $this->_song->getSongsInPlaylist($song); }, $data['songsPlayList']);`

Comment: you soing it wrong. I will post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data['playlistSongs'] = [];
foreach ($data['songsPlayList'] as $key => $value){
  $data['playlistSongs'][] = $this->_song->getSongsInPlaylist($value);
}
var_dump($data['playlistSongs']);
```

other solution:

```
$data['playlistSongs'] = array_map(function($song) use($this) {
  return $this->_song->getSongsInPlaylist($song);
}, $data['songsPlayList']);
```

Comment: I am using this to display my results to webpage  `<?php foreach($data['playlistSongs'] as $key => $value){ ?>
                                        <li><?php echo $value[0][1]; ?> <?php echo $value[0][2]; ?><?php echo $value[0][3]; ?></li>
                                    <?php } ?>` it works well. but reports this error `<p>Error on Sep 05, 2015 16:44PM - Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in  on line 24</p>`